# Deprecation warning on ruby with compass

Tags: ruby, sass, bundler, compass

When I try to run "bundle exec compass watch" as usual on a project, I now have this warning :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of /home/hedy/Sites/mywebsite.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#{$experimental-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of /home/hedy/Sites/mywebsite.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6} "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7} "$ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
```

Every gems are up to date and I don't know how to remove this warning...

Comment: This should be something you can ignore.  You could try upgrading to an alpha version and see if that resolves the problem for you (eg. `gem install compass --pre`).  The deprecation warning is only in Sass 3.4.20; downgrading to 3.4.19 would also eliminate the warning.

Comment: Hummm I already have sass 3.4.19 and I'm using bundler

Comment: If I do a "bundle exec compass compile", the is no warning ! The problem occurs only during watching...

Answer (score 4):

This just happened to me too. I closed out of the terminal and reopened it, then tried `compass watch`, at which point it logged the modified sass file but did not write to the css file. So then I ran `compass clean` followed by `compass watch` again and then it was working properly.

Answer (score -2):

In this case, you just need to stop compass watch command (or restart the cmd) and start the `sass-convert` function that will fix this problem for you. Next time just regularly use `compass watch`. Hope this will help.

Comment: This won't help because the problem is within the modules provided by Compass, not the OP's code.